# @propagate_inbounds in Julia

Tags: julia, bounds-checker

Consider the following case:

```
struct A <: AbstractArray{Int, 2}
    N::Int
end

struct B <: AbstractArray{Int, 2}
    A::A
    Func
end
...
@inline Base.getindex(A::A, i::Int, j::Int) = begin
    @boundscheck (1 <= i <= A.N && 1 <= j <= A.N) || throw(BoundsError())
    i - j
end

Base.@propagate_inbounds Base.getindex(B::B, i::Int, j::Int) = begin
    B.Func(B.A[i, j])
end
```

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/devdocs/boundscheck/) and some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901275/inbounds-propagation-rules-in-julia?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) I was sure that the bounds checks would be eliminated while executing "@inbounds b[i, j]" (b is an array of type B). However, it is not the case. What am I missing?

Comment: How did you test it? Bounds checks are not elided at global scope or if there are any type instabilities. Your example is also missing type annotations on those `getindex` methods.

Comment: @MattB. Oh. I updated the code. Also bounds checks are elimintaed when I use an instance of type A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me using just your definitions:

```
julia> f1(x, i, j) = return x[i,j]
       f2(x, i, j) = @inbounds return x[i,j]

julia> f1(A(5), 123, 123)
ERROR: BoundsError
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex at ./REPL[3]:2 [inlined]
 [2] f1(::A, ::Int64, ::Int64) at ./REPL[4]:1

julia> f2(A(5), 123, 123)
0

julia> f1(B(A(5), identity), 123, 123)
ERROR: BoundsError
Stacktrace:
 [1] getindex at ./REPL[3]:2 [inlined]
 [2] getindex at ./REPL[3]:6 [inlined]
 [3] f1(::B, ::Int64, ::Int64) at ./REPL[4]:1

julia> f2(B(A(5), identity), 123, 123)
0
```

As I mentioned in my comment, `@inbounds` only works when it's in a type-stable function.  Testing it at global scope (like at the REPL) or in a function that's not type stable (like one that references a non-constant global or an abstractly-typed field or array) will not remove those bounds checks.

Note that your definition of `B` will likely lead to type instabilities as Julia cannot know what function it is storing. They're not evident in the minimal example you posted, but this might be the root cause in your more complicated original problem. A better definition would be:

```
struct B{F} <: AbstractArray{Int, 2}
    A::A
    Func::F
end
```